# I cannot update apk and icon google play publisher

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, publishing

I cannot update file apk icon and screenshots on Google play publisher, when we have been publishing for a while, please help me. (Unable to upload error.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change (increment) the `versionCode` in `build.gradle` if you are updating the apk. And, also check the size of icon you are uploading. It must be ***512x512*** pixels.

If you have already done the above steps. Then try opening the Play console in **incognito window** to upload the *apk*. Also, if you have signed in from multiple google accounts, logout from all the accounts (except the one you have used in play console).